javyfX application does not run gui correctly if no monitor connected
I have developed an application in java, specifically under java 8 using the javaFx library. Ultimately, the application is to run on a small computer without a connected display, collect data from other parts of the system, save it and share it with other applications over ethernet. And, if necessary, be accessible via remote desktop solutions such as RustDesk. And while for application development everything works as expected, when I unplug the cable to the screen, the application gui visible in RustDesk stutters, and trying to restart the application ends up showing a black screen. When I plug the screen back in everything works as expected. I've tried using another remote desktop program such as AnyDesk and others, but I get exactly the same thing. Poking around in Windows 10 settings didn't help either.
I tried to use other programs is remote desktop expecting that the problem lies there, unfortunately it did not help. I also changed the windows graphics settings, which unfortunately also had no effect.
Main
package pl.sk2media.skmf.main;
    

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.data_holders.AppSettingHolder;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.uiControllers.MainUiController;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

// by ruszyć aplikację z konsolą z pliku jar "java - jar SKMF AdminerV6c2006 pl.sk2media.skmf.main.class"
public class Main extends Application {
Scene mainScene=null;
    static boolean errorApperance=false;
    public void setTheme(String input)
    {   
            if(!(mainScene.getStylesheets().size()==0))
            {
            mainScene.getStylesheets().remove(0);
            }
            mainScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource(input).toExternalForm());     
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        ConsoleService.logln("Wczytuję root GUI..."); 
        try {           
            FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/MainUI.fxml"));
            AnchorPane root = loader.load();
            mainScene = new Scene(root,610,700);
            
            primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("SKMF Adminer"); 
            //primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
            MainUiController mainUiController=loader.getController();
            AppSettingsServices.setMainScene(this);
            AppSettingsServices.setTheme(AppSettingHolder.appTheme);    
            //mainUiController.setRoot(root);
            primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {                
                @Override
                public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                     event.consume();
                     Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                        alert.setTitle("Zamykanie aplikacji");
                        alert.setHeaderText("Potwierdzenie");
                        alert.setContentText("Jesteś pewien, że chcesz wyjść z aplikacji? Możesz utracić niezapisaną pracę");
                        alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);
                        ButtonType result = alert.showAndWait().orElse(ButtonType.CANCEL);
                        if (result == ButtonType.OK) {
                            mainUiController.killUdpServices();
                            primaryStage.close();
                        }
                }
            });         
            primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
            primaryStage.show();
            if(errorApperance==true)
            {
                MainUiController.showError(3,"Błąd", "Generalny błąd podczas wczytywania ustawień aplikacji.\nTen błąd może być spowodowany niedawną aktualizacją.\nProszę uruchomić ponownię aplikację, lub też skontaktować się z autorem.");
                AppSettingsServices.performSave();
            }
            ConsoleService.logln("Main - Inicjalizaja zakończona");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            ConsoleService.logln("Podczas initializaji aplikacji wystąpił błąd krytyczny."); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsoleService.logln("SKMF Adminer V1.0.1"); 
        ConsoleService.logln("Wczytuję ustawienia..."); 
        try
        {
            AppSettingsServices.initAppSetting();
            AppSettingsServices.performLoad();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorApperance=true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }          
        launch(args);
        ConsoleService.logln("\nAplikacja zakończona."); 
    }
    
}

MainUiController
package pl.sk2media.skmf.uiControllers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
//import java.util.Timer;

//import javafx.animation.Animation;
//import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
//import javafx.geometry.Insets;
//import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.daemons.BackupServiceDaemon;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.daemons.SystemDaemon;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.daemons.serwerDaemon;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.data_holders.AppSettingHolder;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.data_holders.MainDataHolder;
//import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
//import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
//import javafx.util.Duration;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.main.AppSettingsServices;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.main.BackupServices;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.main.CommunicationService;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.main.CommunicationService.commOperationEnum;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.main.ConsoleService;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.main.HelperService;
//import pl.sk2media.skmf.main.StringManagement;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.main.UdpService;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.main.fileService;
import pl.sk2media.skmf.main.fileService.fileOperationEnum;

public class MainUiController
{

    public String appVersion = new String("V0.1.02");
    public String recognizedFileVersion = new String("V0.1.0");
    @FXML private ProgressBar footerProgressBar;
    @FXML private Label footerStatus;
    @FXML private Label footerFileLabel;
    @FXML private Label footerDaemonLabel;
    @FXML private Label adminModeLabel;
//  @FXML private TextField inputLogin;
//  @FXML private TextField inputPassword;
    //@FXML private AnchorPane settingsSpace;
    @FXML private AnchorPane parentAnchorPane;
    @FXML private Button cancelButton;
    @FXML private Button headerUploadButton;
    @FXML private Button headerDownloadButton;
    @FXML private Button headerEepromSaveButton;
    //@FXML private Button headerClearButton;
    @FXML private Button headerAdminLogoutButton;

    @FXML private ToggleButton machineStateButton;
    @FXML private ToggleButton systemStateButton;
    @FXML private ToggleButton stringSettingsButton;
    @FXML private ToggleButton appSettingsButton;
    @FXML private ToggleButton godModeButton;
    @FXML private ToggleButton consoleButton;
    
    
    private Pane actualAppPage;
    private UserSettingController userSettingController;
    private SmsSettingController smsSettingController;
    private EventSettingController eventSettingController;
    private ConsoleController consoleController;
    private MachineStateSettingController machineStateSettingControler;
    private AppSettingController appSettingController;
    private MachineStateController machineStateController;
    //private static AnchorPane mainAnchorPane=null;
    UdpService systemUdpService=null;
    UdpService serwerUdpService = null;
    AppSettingHolder.appModeEnum currentAppMode= null;
    public boolean isGodMode=false;
    
    public void initialize()
    {
        showStatus("Initializuję...");
        ConsoleService.logln("MainUi - Initializuję...");
        setAdminMode(false);
        currentAppMode=AppSettingHolder.appMode;
        ConsoleService.logln(currentAppMode.toString());
        fileService.setMainUiController(this);
        UdpService.setMainUiController(this);
        CommunicationService.setMainUiController(this);
        AppSettingsServices.setMainUiController(this);
        SystemDaemon.setMainUiController(this);
        //serwerDaemon.setMainUiController(this);
        cancelButton.setVisible(false);
        //eventStateDaemon.beginEventStateDaemon();
        showDaemonLabel("Nie uruchomiony"); 
        systemStateButton.setDisable(true); // na czas do póki jeszcze ich nie ma
        stringSettingsButton.setDisable(true); // na czas do póki jeszcze ich nie ma
        BackupServices.setMainUiController(this);
        ConsoleService.logln("MainUi - Initializuję systemUdp...");
        systemUdpService = new UdpService(AppSettingHolder.thisAppPort);
        
        byte temp1 = systemUdpService.initUdpReceiver();
        SystemDaemon.setUdpService(systemUdpService);       
        if (temp1 == 0)
        {
            ConsoleService.logln("MainUi - Łącze zainitializowane");
            CommunicationService.setUdpService(systemUdpService);               
            showStatus("Gotowy");
        } else{
            showStatus("Tryb Offine");
            headerUploadButton.setDisable(true);
            headerDownloadButton.setDisable(true);
            headerEepromSaveButton.setDisable(true);
            showError(3,"Błąd",
                    "Podczas initializacji łącza wystąpił błąd. \nZamknij inne aplikacji mogące zajmować wybrany port.\nAplikacja działa w trybie Ofline.");
        }
        
    
        if(currentAppMode==AppSettingHolder.appModeEnum.SERWER)
        {
        ConsoleService.logln("MainUi - Initializuję serwerUdp...");
        serwerUdpService = new UdpService(AppSettingHolder.serwerPort);
        serwerUdpService.initUdpReceiver();
        serwerDaemon.setUdpService(serwerUdpService);
        }
        if(AppSettingHolder.autoExportEnable==true)
        {
            ConsoleService.logln("MainUi - AutoBackup uruchomiony.");
            BackupServiceDaemon.beginBackupDaemon();
        }
        ConsoleService.logln("MainUi - Initializcja aplikacji zakończona");
        showStatus("Gotowy");
    }

    public void killUdpServices()
    {
        if (systemUdpService != null)
        {
            if (systemUdpService.isReceiverInit == true)
            {
                systemUdpService.endUdpReceiver();
            }
        }
        if (serwerUdpService != null)
        {
            if ((serwerUdpService.isReceiverInit == true) && (serwerUdpService != null))
            {
                serwerUdpService.endUdpReceiver();
            }
        }
    }
    /* public void showNotification(String message)
        {

            final Notification msg = new Notification(message, new FontIcon(Material2OutlinedAL.HELP_OUTLINE));
            msg.getStyleClass().addAll(Styles.BG_WARNING_SUBTLE, Styles.WARNING);
            msg.setPrefHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            msg.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            
            StackPane.setAlignment(msg, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
            StackPane.setMargin(msg, new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0));

            if (!mainAnchorPane.getChildren().contains(msg))
            {

                mainAnchorPane.getChildren().add(msg);
                AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(msg, 50.0);
                AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(msg, 20.0);
                Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
                t.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask()
                {
                    @Override public void run()
                    {
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override public void run()
                            {
                                Animation out = Animations.slideOutRight(msg, Duration.millis(250));
                                out.setOnFinished(f -> mainAnchorPane.getChildren().remove(msg));
                                out.playFromStart();
                            }
                        });
                        t.cancel();
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }
            msg.setOnClose(e -> {
                Animation out = Animations.slideOutRight(msg, Duration.millis(250));
                out.setOnFinished(f -> mainAnchorPane.getChildren().remove(msg));
                out.playFromStart();
            });
        
        }*/
    @FXML
    public void headerButtonClicked(ActionEvent event)
    {

        //smsSettingController.setMultipleDataHolder(smsSettingDataHolder);
        fileService.setMultipleDataHolder(MainDataHolder.smsSettingDataHolder);
        Button clickedButton = (Button) event.getSource();
        String buttonId = clickedButton.getId();

        if (buttonId.equals("headerNewButton"))
        {
            showStatus("Czekam na uzytykownika...");
            if (showConfirmDialog(
                    "Kontynuowanie usunie obecnie edytowaną konfigurację, i utworzy nową, pustą. Kontynuować?",
                    "Potwierdź") == 1)
            {
                File newFile = fileService.showFileSaverDialog("Utwórz nowy plik, lub lub wskaż istniejący",
                        "config.skmfcf");
                fileService.workingFile = newFile;
                fileService.setFileOperation(fileOperationEnum.NEW);
                fileService.startFileThread();
            }
            showStatus("Gotowy.");

        } else if (buttonId.equals("headerSaveButton"))
        {
            if (fileService.workingFile == null)
            {
                showStatus("Czekam na uzytykownika...");
                File newFile = fileService.showFileSaverDialog("Utwórz nowy plik, lub lub wskaż istniejący",
                        "config.skmfcf");

                fileService.workingFile = newFile;
                fileService.setFileOperation(fileOperationEnum.NEW);
                fileService.startFileThread();
                fileService.setFileOperation(fileOperationEnum.SAVE);
                fileService.startFileThread();
            } else
            {
                fileService.setFileOperation(fileOperationEnum.SAVE);
                fileService.startFileThread();

            }

        } else if (buttonId.equals("headerSaveAssButton"))
        {
            showStatus("Czekam na uzytykownika...");
            fileService.temporaryFile = fileService.showFileSaverDialog("Utwórz nowy plik, lub wskaż istniejący",
                    "config.skmfcf");
            fileService.setFileOperation(fileOperationEnum.SAVE_ASS);
            fileService.startFileThread();

        } else if (buttonId.equals("headerLoadButton"))
        {
            showStatus("Czekam na uzytykownika...");
            fileService.workingFile = fileService.showFileLoaderDialog("Wybierz plik do wczytania");
            fileService.setFileOperation(fileOperationEnum.LOAD);
            fileService.startFileThread();
            showStatus("Gotowy.");

        } else if (buttonId.equals("headerUploadButton"))
        {
            showStatus("Czekam na uzytykownika...");
            if (showConfirmDialog(
                    "Kontynuowanie wyśle do sytemu obecnie edytowaną konfigurację, i zastąpi obecnie używaną. Kontynuować? ",
                    "Potwierdź") == 1)
            {
                showStatus("Wysłam dane...");
                CommunicationService.setCommOperation(commOperationEnum.SEND);
                CommunicationService.startCommThread();
            }
            showStatus("Gotowy.");

        } else if (buttonId.equals("headerDownloadButton"))
        {
            showStatus("Czekam na uzytykownika...");
            if (showConfirmDialog(
                    "Kontynuowanie pobierze z systemu używaną konfigurację, i zastąpi nią obecnie edytowaną. Kontynuować? ",
                    "Potwierdź") == 1)
            {
                showStatus("Pobieram dane...");
                CommunicationService.setCommOperation(commOperationEnum.LOAD);
                CommunicationService.startCommThread();
                showStatus("Gotowy.");

            }
            showStatus("Gotowy.");
        } else if (buttonId.equals("headerHelpButton"))
        {
            HelperService helperService = new HelperService();
            helperService.runHelperService();
            
        }/*else if (buttonId.equals("headerClearButton"))
        {
            showStatus("Czekam na uzytykownika...");
            if (showConfirmDialog(
                    "Kontynuowanie rozpocznie procedurę czyszczenia pamięci,usunie to konfigurację aktualnie wgraną. Kontynuować? ",
                    "Potwierdź") == 1)
            {
                showStatus("Wysłam polecenie...");
                CommunicationService.setCommOperation(commOperationEnum.CLEAR);
                CommunicationService.startCommThread();
            }
            
        }*/else if (buttonId.equals("headerEepromSaveButton"))
        {
            showStatus("Czekam na uzytykownika...");
            if (showConfirmDialog(
                    "Kontynuowanie rozpocznie procedurę zapisu konfiguracji do EEPROM. Tej operacji nie można cofnąć. Kontynuować? ",
                    "Potwierdź") == 1)
            {
                showStatus("Wysłam polecenie...");
                CommunicationService.setCommOperation(commOperationEnum.EPRSAVE);
                CommunicationService.startCommThread();
            }
        }else if (buttonId.equals("headerAdminLogoutButton"))
                {
            showError(0,"Do widzienia", "Wylogowano pomyślnie.");
            setAdminMode(false);
                }
    }

    
    @FXML public void godLogin()
    {
        actualAppPage = null;
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/adminLogin.fxml"));
            actualAppPage = loader.load();
            AdminLoginController adminLoginController = loader.getController();
            adminLoginController.setMainUiController(this);
            
            parentAnchorPane.getChildren().clear();
            parentAnchorPane.getChildren().add(actualAppPage);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showError(2,"MERP!", "Błąd podczas wczytywania zakładki adminLogin");
        }
    }
    @FXML public void panelSelectorButtonsAction(ActionEvent event) // zarządzenie widocznością poszczególnych paneli
                                                                // aplikcacji
    {
        ToggleButton clickedButton = (ToggleButton) event.getSource();
        String buttonId = clickedButton.getId();

        actualAppPage = null;
        //TODO chyba można to usunąć
        if (clickedButton.isSelected() == true)
        {
            if (buttonId.equals("machineStateButton"))
            {
                try
                {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/machineState.fxml"));
                    actualAppPage = loader.load();
                    machineStateController = loader.getController();
                    //machineStateController.setDataHolder(MainDataHolder.eventStateDataHolder);
                    //machineStateController.setMainUiController(this);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showError(2,"Błąd", "Błąd podczas wczytywania zakładki machineState");
                }

            } else if (buttonId.equals("systemStateButton"))
            {
                try
                {
                    //TODO tutaj ma być ładowanie kontrolerów i ich przechowywanie, patrz ustawienia
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/systemState.fxml"));
                    actualAppPage = loader.load();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showError(2,"Błąd", "Błąd podczas wczytywania zakładki systemState");
                }

            } else if (buttonId.equals("userSettingsButton"))
            {

                try
                {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/userSetting.fxml"));
                    actualAppPage = loader.load();
                    userSettingController = loader.getController();
                    userSettingController.setDataHolder(MainDataHolder.userSettingDataHolder);
                    userSettingController.setMainUiController(this);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showError(2,"Błąd", "Błąd podczas wczytywania zakładki userSetting");
                }

            } else if (buttonId.equals("smsSettingsButton"))
            {
                try
                {
                    //StringManagement.setUserSettingHolder(MainDataHolder.userSettingDataHolder);
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/smsSetting.fxml"));
                    actualAppPage = loader.load();
                    smsSettingController = loader.getController();
                    smsSettingController.setMainUiController(this);
                    smsSettingController.setMultipleDataHolder(MainDataHolder.smsSettingDataHolder);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showError(2,"Błąd", "Błąd podczas wczytywania zakładki smsSetting");
                }

            } else if (buttonId.equals("eventSettingsButton"))
            {
                try
                {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/eventSetting.fxml"));
                    actualAppPage = loader.load();
                    eventSettingController = loader.getController();
                    eventSettingController.setDataHolder(MainDataHolder.eventSettingsDataHolder);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showError(2,"Błąd", "Błąd podczas wczytywania zakładki eventSetting");
                }

            } else if (buttonId.equals("consoleButton"))
            {
                try
                {
                    //TODO tutaj ma być ładowanie kontrolerów i ich przechowywanie, patrz ustawienia
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/console.fxml"));
                    actualAppPage = loader.load();
                    consoleController = loader.getController();
                    consoleController.setMainUiController(this);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showError(2,"Błąd", "Błąd podczas wczytywania zakładki console");
                }

            } else if (buttonId.equals("godModeButton"))
            {
                try
                {
                    //TODO tutaj ma być ładowanie kontrolerów i ich przechowywanie, patrz ustawienia
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/adminPage.fxml"));
                    actualAppPage = loader.load();
                    AdminPageController adminPageController = loader.getController();
                    adminPageController.setMainUiController(this);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showError(2,"Błąd", "Błąd podczas wczytywania zakładki boga");
                }

            }else if (buttonId.equals("appSettingsButton"))
            {
                try
                {
                    //TODO tutaj ma być ładowanie kontrolerów i ich przechowywanie, patrz ustawienia
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/appSetting.fxml"));
                    actualAppPage = loader.load();
                    appSettingController = loader.getController();
                    appSettingController.setMainUiController(this);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showError(2,"Błąd", "Błąd podczas wczytywania zakładki appSetting");
                }
            }

            try
            {
                parentAnchorPane.getChildren().clear();
                parentAnchorPane.getChildren().add(actualAppPage);
                AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);
                AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);
                AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);
                AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showError(2,"Błąd", "Podczas wczytywania panelu wystąpił błąd krytyczny, dane nie zostały naruszone.");
            }
        }

    }
    
    
    public void showMachineStateSettingPage()
    {
        actualAppPage = null;
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/machineStateSetting.fxml"));
            actualAppPage = loader.load();
            machineStateSettingControler = loader.getController();
            machineStateSettingControler.setDataHolder(AppSettingHolder.eventStateConfigDataholder);
            machineStateSettingControler.setMainUiController(this);
            
            parentAnchorPane.getChildren().clear();
            parentAnchorPane.getChildren().add(actualAppPage);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(actualAppPage, 0.0);

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showError(2,"Błąd", "Błąd podczas wczytywania zakładki machineStateSetting");
        }
    }
    

    public static void showError(int mode,String header, String message)
    {
        Alert alert = null;
        if(mode==0)
        {
            alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, message, ButtonType.OK);
        }else if(mode==1)
        {
            alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, message, ButtonType.OK);
        }else if(mode==2)
        {
            alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, message, ButtonType.OK);
        }else if(mode==3)
        {
            alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING, message, ButtonType.OK);
        }
    
        alert.setTitle("SKMF Adminer");
        alert.setHeaderText(header);
        alert.show();
    }

    public static byte showConfirmDialog(String message, String header)
    {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, message, ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
        alert.setTitle("SKMF Adminer");
        alert.setHeaderText(header);
        alert.showAndWait();
        if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.YES)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.NO)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    

    public void showStatus(String status)
    {
        footerStatus.setText("Status: " + status);
    }

    public void showFile(String status)
    {
        footerFileLabel.setText("Plik: " + status);
    }

    public void showProgress(double progress)
    {
        footerProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
    public void showCancelButton(boolean input)
    {
        cancelButton.setVisible(input);
    }
    public void showDaemonLabel(String input)   
    {
        footerDaemonLabel.setText("Status systemDaemon: "+input);
    }
    public void setAdminMode(boolean input)
    {
        adminModeLabel.setVisible(input);
        isGodMode=input;
        headerAdminLogoutButton.setVisible(input);
        godModeButton.setVisible(input);
        consoleButton.setVisible(input);
    }
}


I haven't tried it with JavaFX, but you might look at headless mode or a virtual server like VNC, Xvfb etc ; more here.

Not seeing any code, we can't know what your issue is. I will guess, though. My guess is that you have threads or loops in your code that are causing the GUI to freeze. I can't give a better guess because you have not posted any code.

Code already added

Try to remove setMaximized().

unfortunately it doesn't help
